# How to check video is actually playing in IOS simulator

Tags: java, video, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I'm using appium and to play a video i'm using javascript executor.
Test always get passed even its not played. Couldn't able to check it as video is lunched in native IOS safari player.

Need to get a way to find video is running in native video player of safari in IOS simulator

Any way i can get to know about video actually played or not

Comment: Take a screenshot before and after and compare the area of the video.

Comment: Share which have you tried as well..